# Async Method of DeleteAsync not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm new to asynchronous programming in c#.

So here is my code:

```
    private async Task testDeleteBank(int id)
    {
        await _msBankRepo.DeleteAsync(id);
        var checkBank = (from A in _msBankRepo.GetAll()
                         where A.Id == id
                         select A).Count();
        if(checkBank > 0)
        {
            Console.Write(checkBank);
        }
    }

    public void testAsync(GetAllBankListDto input)
    {
        testDeleteBank(input.bankID);
        UpdateMsBank(input);
    }
```

When I run testAsync method, it does update a record in my table. But why it's not deleting my record after DeleteAsync method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `await testDeleteBank(input.bankID)` in:

```
public async Task testAsync(GetAllBankListDto input)
{
    await testDeleteBank(input.bankID);
    // UpdateMsBank(input);
}
```

If you *need* `test` to be synchronous, use `AsyncHelper` in:

```
public void test(GetAllBankListDto input)
{
    AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => testDeleteBank(input.bankID));
    // UpdateMsBank(input);
}
```